# UnrealEngine 4.15. Как добавить исходный код библиотеки как зависимость?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4

Прочитал тонну тем на английских форумах по ue4, но так и не разобрался. Хочу добавить исходный код библиотеки в проект и сделать для него адаптер и использовать в игре. Вопрос, как собственно код добавить? Если я просто скину код в `Source` мне придется в каждом файле делать `include "MyProject.h"`, а кода тонна. Да и хотелось бы его отлаживать как отдельное приложение со своим собственным `CMakeLists.txt` и своим фронтендом, а не компилировать каждый минификс в сам UE и отлаживать через него. Просто хотелось бы инклюдить только те хедеры из библиотеки, которые действительно нужны. Гайды очень сложные и не очевидные, возможно кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой. (Делаю кроссплатформенное приложение на android, ios, linux, windows)

Comment: Вам наверное стоит разобраться с работой препроцессора и линкера. Затем выяснить, какие заголовочные файлы и какие бинарные артефакты потребуются для использования бибилотеки. Затем заглянуть в документацию к вашему компилятору / системе сборки и выяснить, как именно там настраивается компилятор и линкер.

Comment: @VTT думаю это не то. Тут достаточно простой случай. На самом деле это даже не совсем библиотека, это код, который от платформы не зависит. Это библитека лишь генерирует определенные данные, есть только исходный код без бинарных артефактов. Вся проблема в обнаружени проблемы именно UE